# add ascending or descending to url in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I am trying to create a url based on the data I get from the user.if we consider this to be my url:

```
  let url = new URL('http://localhost:8080/api/movies/search/search');
```

I add the search fields like this:

```
 for (let item in data) {
      url.searchParams.set(item,data[item]); 
  }
```

but at the end of my url I want to add the sort type for it to look something like this:

```
const url = `http://localhost:8080/api/movies/search/search?title=something&minRate=10&genre=action&sort=title,asc`;
```

so how should I add the last part with the comma:

```
,asc
```

to the url?

Comment: The `data[item]` value for `sort` should contain that information then, no?

Comment: @David
  I originally have sort type in data.sortType and if it is asc or desc in data.type

Comment: If the two values need to be sent to the server as a single value then I imagine you'd just modify `data` to have the keys/values you want before using it to build the search params.  Can you expand the example to include the definition of `data` and demonstrate in what way your attempt isn't working as expected?

Comment: @David  `{title: 'the', minRate: 2, genre: 'action', sortType: 'title', type: 'asc'}` this is how I receive data from user.all I want is to see how could I add the type to the end of the url with a comma like `,asc`.if I add it like `url.searchParams.set(item,data[item]);` it would get added like &type=asc and not ,asc

Comment: My guess is you are trying to append a value to the url object. Try doing `url + ",asc"`  after the loop and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments on the question above...

If `data` is this:

```
{
  title: 'the',
  minRate: 2,
  genre: 'action',
  sortType: 'title',
  type: 'asc'
}
```

And the result you want is this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/movies/search/search?title=the&minRate=2&genre=action&sort=title,asc
```

Then `data` doesn't match what you're looking for.  It has two properties called `sortType` and `type`, and you want one *combined* property called `sort`.

Project the object into the shape you want, then use that new object to build your params:

```js
let data = {
  title: 'the',
  minRate: 2,
  genre: 'action',
  sortType: 'title',
  type: 'asc'
};

let url = new URL('http://localhost:8080/api/movies/search/search');

// create the object you want:
let urlData = {
  title: data.title,
  minRate: data.minRate,
  genre: data.genre,
  sort: `${data.sortType},${data.type}`
};

// then add params from *that* object:
for (let item in urlData) {
  url.searchParams.set(item, urlData[item]); 
}

console.log(url);
```

(Note that the `,` character is URL-encoded by default.)

Basically, don't change the *logic* to work around the *data structure*.  Keep the logic simple and change the *data structure* to what you need it to be.

Comment: I get it now. definitely should take note of the last sentence.thank you.

Comment: @Elham: As always, someone else has of course said it better than I can... *"Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around." - Eric S. Raymond, The Cathedral & the Bazaar* :)